# Is there an option for netbeans to allow code completion for private properties outside the class?

Tags: php, netbeans

Like the question states , can i set an option to show code hints about private properties ouside a class (PHP editor) ? I'm using netbeans 7.2 .

Comment: I hope not!!! If you need to see it outside then it shouldn't be private!

Comment: There might be some cases when you use the magic methods to get/set private properties (writing getters/setters takes alot more effort). Netbeans does not interpret these magic methods

Comment: as for getters/setters NetBeans can autogenerate them for you - when in class body use alt+insert -> Getter/Setter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to create docblock for class and use `@property` annotation:

```
/**
 * @property string $bar Baz
 */
class foo {
    private $bar;
}
```

Comment: I had some problems but when I put the block just before to the class declaration, works fine.